# dyld: Symbol not found: _NSFontAttributeName

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode4, dyld

I am getting this error when running a library I created in a third-party project on iOS 5. The project compiles just fine but right upon startup I get the following in my console:

```
dyld: Symbol not found: _NSFontAttributeName
  Referenced from: /Users/Stunner/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.0/Applications/C26FFA60-BB4A-4321-908A-0EF8756F47D3/An.app/An
  Expected in: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
 in /Users/Stunner/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.0/Applications/C26FFA60-BB4A-4321-908A-0EF8756F47D3/An.app/An
```

What perplexes me is that I have a sample app for the library I created, and when run on iOS 5, it runs fine. I am suspecting that there may be additional build settings in the third-party application that is causing me to see this error.

In my sample app I have the following linker flag:

```
-ObjC
```

The third party app has these:

```
-ObjC -lxml2 -lz -all_load
```

Comment: `NSFontAttributeName` was added in iOS 6. You can't use it in iOS 5.

Comment: Ya, I understand, but why isn't this happening at compile time? Additionally, this works fine in my sample app on iOS 5, but not on the third party app.

Comment: If your Base SDK is iOS 6 or later, you won't get a compiler error because it's a valid symbol in that case. It only becomes a runtime error when the code is run under iOS 5 or earlier.

Comment: I see... so if I wanted to still use `NSFontAttributeName` in my library and have it be included in projects that support pre iOS 6.0 what do I do? By the way the base SDK on the third-party project is iOS 6.1 and I am deploying to iOS 5. What is really confusing is why this works just fine in my sample application that I use for testing my library... (I can run it just fine on iOS 5 with base SDK 6.1 in my sample app).

Comment: You need to do a runtime check for the constant and use `NSFontAttributeName` is it exists otherwise use some other appropriate constant.

Comment: Yeah that makes sense... the way my library works is it actually does a runtime check to ensure it is on iOS 6, otherwise it doesn't even allow itself to be used. The bit of code where NSFontAttributeName is used isn't called at all. That's why I don't think a runtime check will work. Seems like a compiler error isn't appearing until runtime... The challenge looks to be determining what target of iOS the third party app is being compiled for... which doesn't seem to be possible, unless I am missing something. I am going to see if I can find the raw value of NSFontAttributeName, and use that.